# Exception thrown by async function is intercepted by crashlytics

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, crashlytics

I have the following function:

```
class CannotOpenMapException implements Exception {}

void launchMap(String address) async {
  …
  throw CannotOpenMapException();
}
```

And then in an `onTap` handler:

```
onTap: () {
  try {
    launchMap(my_address);
  } on CannotOpenMapException {
    print('caught exception!');
  }
}
```

Thing is, the exception is not caught, the `print` statement is never executed.

I think the problem is with the way I start Crashlytics (though this is how [the official docs recommend it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter#configure-crash-handlers)):

```
void main() async {
  runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
    …
    runApp(const MyApp());
  },
    (error, stack) =>
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true));
}
```

Is there a way I can make Crashlytics only catch the exception I don't catch?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second argument "onError" of runZoneGuarder, this way only the exceptions that's you don't catch are intercepted.

```
runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    ... and stuff

    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack);
  });
```

The doc:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html

Comment: I forgot the `(error, stack)` part in the code snippet in the question, fixed it now

Comment: you mention onError, but your code snippet doesn't use onError, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: The `onTap` handler was not `async`, so it just started `launchMap` and then exited. Now the `launchMap` execution was running "detached" (not sure that is the correct word for it). In order to catch it, `onTap` needs to be async and use the `await` keyword:

```
onTap: () async {
  try {
    await launchMap(widget.listing.address());
  } on CannotOpenMapException {
    …
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () {
   try {
      await launchMap(my_address);
   } on CannotOpenMapException {
      print('caught exception!');
   }
}
```

if you want to use async then use await.

Comment: yes, I found out and published an answer already half an hour ago, why did you add a new answer?